# Create a not null column with values from other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a NOT NULL column in my table with values from an other column as default values. How I can do that?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
    ADD COLUMN not_null_column TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT old_column
```

but that not works because old_column is not constant

Any idea?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: "_that not works because old_column is not constant_" Define "not works". What should happen? What happens instead? What does it mean for a column not to be constant, and how does that related to a default value on another column?

Comment: I need to do a migration with flyway, but I can manage my db with Intellij's tool

Comment: @underscore_d constant is something like '2021-01-45' written in raw.


It's not working means my migration can't be applied, an error pops

Comment: You could add the column them update it: `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN not_null_column TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW();
UPDATE mytable SET not_null_column=old_column;`

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

The reason is explained in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-DESCRIPTION) where the DEFAULT clause in a CREATE TABLE is documented:

> The DEFAULT clause assigns a default data value for the column whose column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free expression (**in particular, cross-references to other columns in the current table are not allowed**).

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

If you really need something like that, you will have to create a (before insert) trigger that populates `not_null_column` with the value of the other column.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that :

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
    ADD COLUMN not_null_column TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE;

UPDATE mytable
SET not_null_column = old_column;


ALTER TABLE mytable
    ALTER COLUMN not_null_column SET NOT NULL;
```